# Will ROS live on without Willow?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2013/02/11/willow-garage-changing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54988/will-ros-live-on-without-willow?/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2013-02-11

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**WE** won't let it die!

[ROS at OSRF](http://osrfoundation.org/blog/ros-at-osrf.html)

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We won't let it die.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Should Willow Garage one day decide to drop the contribution to ROS, ROS will remain an open-source project like any other that will remain active as long as there is sufficient interest in the topic and nothing better around to replace it.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8